# Errors while making tdlib example

Tags: cmake

l am trying to build a java example for the td lib following the README(https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java)
I have got following mistackes. Please tell how can I fix it?

```
C:\Users\irina\td\jnibuild>cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DTD_ENABLE_JNI=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../example/java/td ..
-- Could NOT find ccache
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include optimized;C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/ssleay32MD.lib;debug;C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/ssleay32MDd.lib;optimized;C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/libeay32MD.lib;debug;C:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib/VC/libeay32MDd.lib
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:256 (message):
  Not found zlib: skip TDLib, tdactor, tdnet, tddb


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
ZLIB_LIBRARY
    linked by target "tdutils" in directory C:/Users/irina/td/tdutils

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/irina/td/jnibuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/irina/td/jnibuild/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: zlib is a library on linux systems, but I'm not sure if it's on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

**ZLIB for Windows** is a part of the **GnuWin32** project (I'm not sure whether it is allowed to give links on SO). As I see, the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) uses  `find_package` to lookup the `ZLIB` library:

```
if (NOT ZLIB_FOUND)
  find_package(ZLIB)
endif()
if (NOT ZLIB_FOUND)
  message(WARNING "Not found zlib: skip TDLib, tdactor, tdnet, tddb")
  return()
endif()
```

How the `find_package` command works is well described in the [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html):

> The command has two modes by which it searches for packages: “Module” mode and 
>   “Config” mode. Module mode is available when the command is invoked with the 
>   above reduced signature. CMake searches for a file called **Find<package>.cmake** 
>   in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` followed by the CMake installation. If the file is 
>   found, it is read and processed by CMake. It is responsible for finding the 
>   package, checking the version, and producing any needed messages. Many find-
>   modules provide limited or no support for versioning; check the module 
>   documentation. If no module is found and the `MODULE` option is not given the 
>   command proceeds to Config mode.

I've had a look into `FindZLIB.cmake` on my Windows machine. The module uses the following path: **ZLIB_ROOT** and the following registry keys:

**"[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GnuWin32\Zlib;InstallPath]"
        "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/zlib**

So, as I understand, if you install **GnuWin32** using the installer, the `HKLM` key will be written down into the registry and CMake will be able to find the path to `ZLIB`. If you wish to use just the zip-archive, the `ZLIB_ROOT` parameter must be correctly specified when you run CMake:

```
cmake -DZLIB_ROOT=<PATH-to-your-unpacked-zlib> -D.....
```